# Best way to download a github repo that uses cocoa pods?

Tags: github, cocoapods

I am following a github repository. When I go to create the podfile using `pod init` the terminal says

```
[!] Existing Podfile found in directory
```

When I show the project in the finder, I see a pdfile as a `exec` instead of a text file so to speak.

[image]

Should I delete it and run `pod init` once more? What is the best way to successfully clone this github repo using cocoa pods?

Answer (score 0):

Thats all right. You can open it via any text editor (like Sublime Text). Or just run `pod install`, open your `Demo.xcworkspace` and in `Pods` you will see your `Podfile`.So you can edit it directly from `Xcode`.